# Show immediately the keyboard in a new view

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

I have a problem with the visibility of the keyboard in a view:
I have an activity with its own view (layout) that contains a button "new".
Clicking on the button is superimposed on a view (layout) with a transparent background and an EditText.

My question is:

I would like to bring up the keyboard immediately when I click on "new" and the new screen appears, I click on that new, new screen appears with the keyboard and click on the EditText without sull'edittext to bring up the keyboard. I hope I explained. How can I do?

Comment: You should post code, so we can see what already you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following line to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Answer (score 0):

Programatically:

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Through xml:

```
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

either will set the focus on the your edittext at the beginning and as such will bring up  your keyboard.